# Adding Classes to a Solution MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, linux, monodevelop

I was trying to create a new project in C# in MonoDevelop. I first created a new Console Project, which generated my Main(). Then, I used File->New->New Solution... From there, I chose to add a library via Other->.NET->Library. I named the project name apart from my original console project, but I made sure the library's solution name and the console project's solution name are the same. Only the project names are different.

I can search the solution in the search engine in MonoDevelop. Both the main class and the automatic library class appear. I then try to reference this library class in my main, but I cannot. I try to click on the console project's references via Project->Edit References, but the edit references tab is grayed out.

I've tried to incorporate the library into the console project via using statements, but that does not work.

The MonoDevelop tutorials say to right click on the solution icon in the solutions tab, but I cannot find any such thing. The closest is Project-->Edit References.

Can anyone offer any insight to this? Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm a little confused at what you're doing. If you've already created a Console project (which will have created a Solution as well), did you add a Library Project to that Solution or create a new Solution with a Library project in it? The method you describe above would have created a new Solution, I'm not sure that's what you want?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to add class to your solution: File -> Add -> New File... -> C# -> General -> Empty class ;)